# webpack2: configuring module rules

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm using webpack@2.6.1

My config is pretty simple:

```
{
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      SRC_ROOT,
      "node_modules",
    ],
  },

  entry: "index.js",

  output: {
    path: sysPath.join(APP_ROOT, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/i,
        include: SRC_ROOT,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "eslint-loader",
            enforce: "pre",
            options: {
              failOnError: true,
              failOnWarning: true,
            },
          },

          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

And when I run it, I got following:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0].use should be one of these:
   non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? } | function | [non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? }]
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be an instance of function.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be an object.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be one of these:
      non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? }
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be an instance of function.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] should be an instance of function.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] has an unknown property 'enforce'. These properties are valid:
      object { loader?, options?, query? }
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? }
```

I'm confused, because these errors are totally contradict to what I see in docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options.

Arrays in "use" are not supported? "unknown property 'enforce'"? How is it even possible, when doc shows exactly the same usage examples?

Please explain what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: can you show your full config, and how you use it ?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli it's a full config. Then I just run "node_modules/.bin/webpack".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `enforce` is not a valid property on a loader. It must be used on a rule, hence it's [`Rule.enforce`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-enforce) in the docs. The following line of the error message tells you that it's not a valid property:

```
* configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] has an unknown property 'enforce'. These properties are valid:
  object { loader?, options?, query? }
```

It doesn't show `use` to be a valid property, because internally `use`, `loaders` and `loader` are treated as aliases.

You'd have to put `enforce` on the entire rule.

```
{
  test: /\.js$/i,
  enforce: "pre",
  include: SRC_ROOT,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "eslint-loader",
      options: {
        failOnError: true,
        failOnWarning: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: "babel-loader",
    }
  ],
}
```

But you don't really want `babel-loader` to be a pre-loader and that means you need to create two separate rules.

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/i,
    enforce: "pre",
    include: SRC_ROOT,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          failOnError: true,
          failOnWarning: true,
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/i,
    include: SRC_ROOT,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I've purposely kept the explicit version of the rules. You can indeed use some shortcuts, one of them being that if you only use a single loader, you may specify `options` directly on the rule. The options will be forwarded to the loader, which is probably why you thought that `enforce` is valid on a loader.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. I missed the difference between Rules and UseEntries. 

Just curious – will it be correct to use nested rules to achieve the same result? Like this:

rules: [
  {
    test: ...,
    rules: [ { loader: "...", enforce: "pre" }, { loader: "..." }  ] 
} ]

Comment: I personally wouldn't do it, because you only save a few characters but it increase the complexity by nesting the rules. I'd much rather have all rules at at the top level, so it's easy to understand them, especially in isolation.

Comment: But technically it will work. Well, on my view, grouping everything which processes same file types, is not so bad approach. But I agreed, that with complex configs, especially when it is split on multiple files and then deeply merged somehow, it can complicate things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use two different objects inside your `rules`

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/i,
      include: SRC_ROOT,
      loader: "eslint-loader",
      enforce: "pre",
      options: {
        failOnError: true,
        failOnWarning: true,
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/i,
      include: SRC_ROOT,
      loader: "babel-loader",
    }    
  ]
}
```

It's a bit redundant but it should work

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed.
Though, the question "how is it even possible" remains opened.

Comment: Yeah it looks weird but the documentation shows a string first and after that an object. I know it's just an example of what you can use but why don't you try to put `babel-loader` as a string at first place? Just like the example

Comment: Defining loader as just a string is not a problem. And I tried it too.
Webpack complains that it does not know "enforce" option (which is present in doc) and that value of "use" option can't be an array (which is also in doc). I.e., it fails before getting to babel-loader config.